# Installation error of python package using pip

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, pip, python-module

I tried to install a python module called python-phonenumbers
I got this error

sudo pip install git+git://github.com/daviddrysdale/python-phonenumbers.git

> Cleaning up... Command /usr/bin/python -c "import
>   setuptools;**file**='/tmp/pip-YQ6XJC-build/setup.py';exec(compile(open(**file**).read().replace('\r\n',
>   '\n'), **file**, 'exec'))" install --record
>   /tmp/pip-s3GdMz-record/install-record.txt
>   --single-version-externally-managed failed with error code -9 in /tmp/pip-YQ6XJC-build Storing complete log in
>   /home/ubuntu/.pip/pip.log

I attached the complete log here 
http://paste2.org/WZzCdz7Y

**update**

I mistakenly put the following line

```
 sudo pip install git://github.com/daviddrysdale/python-phonenumbers.git
```

instead of

```
sudo pip install git+git://github.com/daviddrysdale/python-phonenumbers.git
```

Comment: I'm getting the same error with `pip install phonenumbers==6.0.0`

Comment: @Mark0978 see below - looks like is a known / active issue with the latest version

Comment: Yea, I found the open issue after I posted that comment here.  I changed to pip install phonenumber<6.0.0 and it install's just fine.  The potential of this to blow up my website is not without concern, but I have intention of loading the geodata so hopefully this will not be a problem

Answer (score 3):

This is not in response to the original failure, but to others who have come in from Google (like I have) since the 6.0 release. It looks like this a memory bug introduced by an increase in the geodata in the latest release, and so will fail on systems with a limited amount of memory available at the time of install. The issue is being tracked here: https://github.com/daviddrysdale/python-phonenumbers