# pip install returns -9

Tags: python, pip, openshift, error-code

I am running a source-to-image on a openshift environment, in this environment, pip will use the `requirements.txt` file to install multiple packages.

During install of some packages we have the error:

```
Collecting itsdangerous==0.24 (from -r requirements.txt (line 7))
Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/dc/b4/a60bcdba945c00f6d608d8975131ab3f25b22f2bcfe1dab221165194b2d4/itsdangerous-0.24.tar.gz (46kB)
Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code -9 in /tmp/pip-build-1sttjqx7/itsdangerous/
```

Looking in the internet there is no information on the specific error code "failed with error code -9".

Tips on what is the actual meaning of -9 ?

Comment: I guess it's a memory issue. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19632714/installation-error-of-python-package-using-pip

Comment: Maybe try to download and install the `.tar.gz` manually from pypi to get the actual output of the `python setup.py` call

Answer (score 0):

The openshift platform was configured to use the following default values of cpu: 25milicores and 64Mib of memory. Therefore the problem was caused by a lack of memory.

For the record, the openshift yaml can be configured with extra resources as indicated in this link [enter link description [here](https://docs.openshift.com/online/dev_guide/builds/advanced_build_operations.html)